# Increment value then reset Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code :

```js
var i = 1;
var limit = 6;

$('button').click(function() {
 $('p').html('');

  if(i <= limit) {
   $('p').append(i++);
  } else {
   alert('stop !');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>

</p>
<button>Increase</button>
```

What I want is when `i` reach `limit`, `i` goes back to 1 and then increase when the button is clicked etc ....

Thanks for your help !

Comment: so set `i=1`  in the else block?

Answer (score 1):

**Better solution without using variables.** This is easier than you think. You don't even need a new variable:

```js
$(function () {
  var limit = 6;
  $("button").click(function () {
    if (parseInt($("p").text().trim()) < limit)
      $("p").text(parseInt($("p").text().trim()) + 1);
    else
      $("p").text(1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1</p>
<button>Increase</button>
```

But seriously, to make your stuff work, you just replace your `alert()` with `i = 1`. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `i=1;` after your alert:

```js
var i = 1;
var limit = 6;

$('button').click(function() {
  $('p').html('');

  if (i <= limit) {
    $('p').append(i++);
  } else {
    alert('stop !');
    i=1;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>

</p>
<button>Increase</button>
```